# Are there API ways to get the data about the offers on OpenSea? Without OpenSea API

Tags: nft, python, opensea

I'll try to be clear! Let me have some `address = "Ox.."`

I want to see all the information on the **offers** this address makes on OpenSea
Are there ways to accomplish this using the alchemy API?
The only thing I found from alchemy is the nftsales api, but I don't want sales I want **offers**!

Comment: of course, every application based on the blockchain gathers data from the blockchain , which is public and can be read by anyone, even if you don't provide the ABI of the contracts, you can still decompile and derive what's the data and where it is stored. The storage of the contract may be dumped upon request and you will have all its internal variables (of storage type)

Comment: and since opensea is based on ERC721 the job of decompiling can be avoided

Comment: @Nulik I need more technical details on how to do this specifically for opensea. Thank you chatgpt

Answer (score 1):

No this wont be possible. Opensea offers are stored off-chain until they are acted upon, so wont be visible via Alchemy. They're stored on Opensea's servers, and the only way to access them is by querying Opensea's API.